# Keyword Query Language to get all the Items holding particular SharePoint Security group from Site Collection

Tags: ssom, keywordquery, kql, keyword-query-language

I have requirement to get all the items from Lists & Document Libraries of entire site collections holding SharePoint Security group name "Inspection" using Keyword Query Language.

Can any one help me how can I do this.

Comment: What you mean for 'Security Group Name'? Is it unique permission of item OR Column which contains 'Inspection' Value?

Comment: It's sharepoint group